# How Can I Use the Keyboard to Scroll Photos

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, photography

I have a small photography portfolio site that I use to share pictures with my relatives. The photos are laid out every 1000px or so in a vertical scrolling page. An example is here: http://pavelrozman.com/photo/events/jamison/ . Right now I have a small Javascript that lets you scroll 800px with the arrow keys. This is okay, but it's inconsistent because of varying image heights. I read an article on The Verge, and it has exactly what I'm looking for but I have no idea how to implement it because I know nothing about Javascript/jQuery. The article is here http://www.theverge.com/2013/7/29/4560214/point-and-shoot-perfection-an-evening-with-sonys-rx100m2 and I'd like to copy the "Use 'd' and 's' to scroll" feature where it scrolls to the top of the next or previous image, but use the arrow keys instead of 's' and 'd' if possible.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: What am I supposed to be seeing at that Verge article?  I don't see anything remarkable there at all.

Comment: If you scroll down to where the photos are, it lets you use the keys 'd' and 's' to advance to the next photograph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, make a list of the `top` offsets of each image, and then when pressing the down/up arrows, compare the `scrollTop` position to the image positions to determine which one is closest in the up/down direction.

```
var locs = [];

// Save offsets of each image
// Use a better selector in real life
$('img').each(function () {
    locs.push($(this).offset().top);
});

$(document).keydown(function (e) {

    switch (e.which) {
        case 37:
        case 38:
        case 83:
            // Get the current scroll position 
            var sTop = parseInt($(document).scrollTop());

            // For UP, go through the list backward until
            // you find one before the current scroll position
            for (i = locs.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (locs[i] < sTop) {
                    $(document).scrollTop(locs[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        case 39:
        case 40:
        case 68:
            // Get the current scroll position 
            var sTop = parseInt($(document).scrollTop());

            // For DOWN, go through the list until
            // you find one after the current scroll position
            for (i = 0; i < locs.length; i++) {
                if (locs[i] > sTop + 1) {
                    $(document).scrollTop(locs[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9BEbh/

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate the time this took you. I played with it in the JSFiddle and it works perfectly. When I copied that code and put it into a document just as you have it in JSFiddle it didn't work in Safari, any suggestions?

Comment: I didn't add jQuery to my document. Once I added jQuery, this worked beautifully. Thank you so much for your time and knowledge!

Comment: No problem.  If you found my answer useful, click the check mark on the left of my answer to accept it.

Comment: Checked! Thanks so much: test it out at http://pavelrozman.com/photo/events/jamison/